# can't get PATH and PYTHONPATH configured properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am struggling with achieving the right settings for PATH and PYTHONPATH.

My main objective is to update pip via Command Prompt, via

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

while in the prompt C:\Users\John Doe>

This results in

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

As an aside, I can successfully run

```
pip install <xxxx>
```

'pip.exe' is located in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts and 'python.exe' is located in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\

My environment variables currently look like

**User variables for John Doe**:

Path `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`

PYTHONPATH: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

**System variables**:

PYTHONPATH: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

(I didn't add this folder to the 'Path' under System variables)

any help appreciated!

Comment: where python.exe prints 

C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: What's your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Windows' fault. For some unfathomable reason, there is a default `python.exe` that does nothing except redirect to the Windows Store. To fix this, go to `Settings -> Manage App Execution Aliases` and disable `python.exe` and `python3.exe`.